# Replication feature in SQL Server 2017 on Linux

Tags: sql-server, replication, sql-server-2017, linux

We have a running production using SQL-Server 2014 in production. It has replication running and partial subscribers in several data centers.
I had a request to evaluate SQL Server 2017 on Linux so it could serve for a new application running on Linux.
The issue is that it should be a subscriber as well and seems that Microsoft doesn't have replication in development yet.

Have someone already handled this issue of replication in any way?

Is Replication supported in SQL Server on Linux?

I opened a [connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/3144371/replication-for-sql-server-on-linux) and perhaps some of you would vote for it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the moment, replication is not supported on Linux. However, according to the release notes, replication support will be added in a future release.

[Release notes for SQL Server 2017 on Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-release-notes)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I actually understood from it before that they are unsure if it will be added. But seems that you are right.

Comment: I expect it to be added soon but I'm unsure what the timeline is. Hopefully someone from Microsoft will comment on your Connect item and let us know.

Comment: Is this now available?

Answer (score 2):

It is available with SQL 2019 preview - [SQL Server Replication on Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-replication?view=sql-server-ver15)

> SQL Server 2019 preview introduces SQL Server Replication for instances of SQL Server on Linux.
>
> Configure replication on Linux with SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) replication stored procedures.

It does have some limitations still compared to the Windows version of the product though:

> SQL Server 2019 preview does not support the following features:
>
> - Immediate update subscribers
> - Oracle publishing