# MS SQL Server Error: Replication components are not installed on this server on Ubuntu

Tags: sql-server, ubuntu, merge-replication

We have a Windows 10 SQL Server 2014 Standard License I'm using on our local computer. Trying to replicate a database to an Ubuntu Server 18.x with SQL Server 2018 ([installed using this easy guide](https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-installation-troubleshooting-on-ubuntu/)).

I've [completed the replication steps on my local PC (using this guide)](https://www.iperiusbackup.net/en/sql-server-merge-replication-ftp-guide-remote-database-synchronization/), but when I try to setup Subscription using SSMS 2018 I get the error below

**Replication components are not installed on this server on Ubuntu**

I've tried:

1. Reinstalling the SQL Server on Ubuntu as recommended by most Microsoft forums  like [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/50e31448-a5be-4263-8248-6ba7bae75262/mssql-for-linux-replication-component-not-installed?forum=sqldatabaseengine) and [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/64c041f5-3822-408f-b072-99feb18a5fcc/replication-components-are-not-installed?forum=sqlreplication) to no avail. The instructions point to a command with .exe:

   You need to run setup again and install the replication components. You can do this from the command line like this:

   ```
   setup.exe /q /Features=Replication /InstanceName=MSSQLSERVER /ACTION=INSTALL /IAcceptSQLServerLicenseTerms
   ```
2. **Edit 2:** [This](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/191785/replication-feature-in-sql-server-2017-on-linux) says Replication isnt supported on Linux SQL Server 2017

Answer (score 1):

Confirmed. Replication on Linux begins with SQL Server 2019 according to [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-replication?view=sql-server-ver15)

> SQL Server 2019 introduces SQL Server Replication for instances of SQL Server on Linux.